# Finding limit from open interval

Tags: calculus, limits

If $2-x^2\le g(x)\le2$ $\cos x$ for all $x$ in some open interval containing $0$, find $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$.

I've been trying to solve it using $\epsilon$ $\delta$.But no luck. :(

Comment: Do you ***have*** to solve it using the definition $(\epsilon -\delta)$?

Comment: No.I tried it because i didn't know any other way.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22) (e.g. you mention you've been attempting the epsilon-delta, but could you show us what you've tried?). Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines) run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, assuming you know that the functions $2-x^2$ and $2\cos x$ are continuous, we employ the "[Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)" for $h(x)=2-x^2, f(x)=2\cos x, g(x)$

for which we know that the inequality $h(x)\le g(x)\le f(x)$ is true, to obtain $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(2-x^2)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}2 \cos x=2$$

Thus we get the desired result.